# Python dataclasses.replace not working for InitVar

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I'm finding I have issues with the dataclasses.replace function. For example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, InitVar, replace

@dataclass
class test_class:
    int_value: InitVar[int] = None
    float_value: float = None

    def __post_init__(self, int_value):
        self.float_value = float(int_value)

c1 = test_class(10)
replace(c1, float_value=20.)
```

Gives me

> ValueError: InitVar 'int_value' must be specified with replace()

Logically, I would not expect to have to pass int_value in the replace function, because it already has a default set, and in that the documentation seems to agree with me (from https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html):

Init-only variables without default values, if any exist, must be specified on the call to `replace()` so that they can be passed to `__init__()` and `__post_init__()`.

Since int_value has a default value specified, I can't reconcile this. Am I wrong is there something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: whats is the expected output?

Comment: @BSQL: `test_class(float_value=20.0)`

Answer (score 1):

It actually seems this is an acknowledged bug:
https://bugs.python.org/issue36470